# How to set session variables with app.get() in Ruby on Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I manually set session while calling `app.get()` in `script/console`?

For example I want to access an authorised page, but it always redirects me to sign-in page. How can I set the session before calling `app.get()` so that I can make an authorised call to that page?

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you are using for session authentication. if you do `app.class`, you will see that app is an `ActionController::Integration::Session`. What you need to do is authenticate yourself, then hitting your restricted pages should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly workaround that I did.

```
#Type in script/console
include ActionController::TestProcess
@request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
@response = ActionController::TestResponse.new
@controller = SomeController.new
get 'action', {}, {:signed => 42} #action, params, session
#now @response has the updated response object.
```

Before doing another `get()/post() etc` make sure you reset `@controller` by calling `@controller = SomeController.new`, or else `@response` doesn't seem to get updated on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

The session is readable (http://tektastic.com/2006/12/ruby-on-rails-how-to-load-session.html) if you pull the temp file in, but unless you're using debugger, then no the session hash is not stored in a way that it can be modified from the console.

Answer (score -1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

This will help u..